# css page curl effect drop shadow with rotate

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I'm attempting to rotate a div to which I have applied a 'page curl' drop shadow.

The page curl drop shadow effect is working fine until I rotate the div, at which point the drop shadow elements show up through the div (z-index issue)?

I've also noticed that if I have an image as the div content, I don't get this issue, but I'd love to get it working for a div with text content. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

CSS (vendor prefixes removed to shorten code, but the problem is occurring across all modern browsers):

```
.shadow {border:1px solid #ccc;position:relative;width:300px;height:116px;background-color:#ededed;}

.shadow:before, .shadow:after {            
    bottom:13px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-11deg);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left:3px;
}
.shadow:after {
    -moz-transform: rotate(11deg);
    left: auto;
    right: 2px;
}

.rotate{
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="shadow">this is the first div</div> <!-- this one is ok -->
    <div class="shadow rotate">this is the second div</div> <!-- this has the issue -->
    <div class="shadow rotate"><img src="//www.google.com/logos/2012/Teachers_Day_Alt-2012-hp.jpg" width="300" height="116"></div> <!-- this one is ok -->
```

And here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/U8qY3/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice job!

As a workaround, you can put a DIV inside the rotated div, with background-colour set to underneath one, and full height and width, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U8qY3/6/

HTML

```
<div class="shadow rotate">
    <div class="workaround">this is the second div</div>         
</div>
```

CSS

```
.workaround{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ededed;
}
```

Comment: that's it! you guys are so *quick*. and it works across the other modern browsers too.

Comment: ps. i can take no credit for the ingenious drop shadow effect. i found it 'on the internet'.